# PNG image display from SD card of Android

Tags: android, image, png, transparency, sd-card

I have saved a transparent PNG image in the SD card. I want to display is now. I was using the follwing code for that.

```
selected_photo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.selected_photo);
Uri photoUri = Uri.parse(photoPath);
                        selected_photo.setImageBitmap(MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),photoUri));
```

But it is giving a not transparent image in display. How to display the PNG image without loosing the transparency?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MediaStore API is probably throwing away the alpha channel (i.e. decoding to RGB565). If you have a file path, just use BitmapFactory directly, but tell it to use a format that preserves alpha:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, options);
selected_photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```